# Figuring out Memory Leaks

Tags: swift, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have several memory leaks in my application, I tried to profile it with instruments but I can not really figure it out. 
[image]

[image]
Is it normal for a delegate that it is possible to click through the delegate?
The delegate is a weak var:
weak var delegate: NavigationToJournalDetailVC?
I actually do not think it is the delegate that leaks memory. But I can not figure it out what else it could be.

I am using coordinators for the navigation. But all the ViewControllers get deinitialised correctly, but the memory goes not all the way down. Does anyone have an idea what it could be?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your `NavigationToJournalDetailVC` has a reference to the `JournalListViewController` via the `journalListViewController` property? This is creating a circular dependency - do you need that property?